# How to fix github after a wrong push

Tags: github

My team-mate "accidentally" pushed a 2 commits to github breaking our branching model.

I want to revert my github repository as it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
git clone url project
cd project
git reset HEAD^^ --hard
git push --force
```